# A verb to imply something has made you feel not tired anymore

Tags: word-request, idioms, expressions, phrases

Work can wear you out, whether your job requires physical labor or not.
Imagine you feel really tired due to a long time of hard work either (either mentally or physically), or when you are back home after a truly difficult day, and you het a very good news.
Or let's suppose you are on your way home after a laborious working day or daily demands of your job, and suddenly, run into an old friend who you have been looking for since a couple of months ago.

Prior to these incidents, you used to feel exhausted. But as soon as you hear the amazing news or when meet the one who you were yearning to find in some way, you **get your energy back, feel boosted and
feel you have already recovered from exhaustion.**

I would be most grateful if you could let me know What is the English verb / expression / idiom which is used when you **feel good again after "tiredness / exhaustion"** [i.e. takes your tiredness away - direct translation from Turkish] in everyday speech?

Comment: By the way, your question is perfectly comprehensible and unambiguous, but I noticed "you feel a very good news", which isn't grammatical; a native speaker might phrase it as "you receive a very good piece of news".

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I see; I'm sorry for the typo. Thank you for pointing that out. I will fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I've been [*reinvigorated*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reinvigorate).

> to give new or renewed strength or energy to (something or someone) : to invigorate (something or someone) again

Comment: I'd also recommend 'energised.'

Comment: I considered "energised", and even edited it out of an earlier draft of this answer, but "energised" isn't solely used to indicate moving from a state of tiredness to vigour; it can mean moving from a normal state to a state of vigour.

Comment: (I guess "re-energised" would be fine though.)

Answer (score 1):

Please see the Cambridge dictionary definition of the verb to "**[invigorate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/invigorate)**".

You can say:

> I feel invigorated

or

> It invigorated me

The verb derives from the word "**[vigor](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vigor)**",  the Cambridge dictionary definition of which exudes all of the sentiments that you listed.

You can also use the verb to "**re**invigorate" which implies that you've regained your enthusiasm, rather than discovered it for the first time.